# Office 365 Mail folder listing API returning 404 with message folder not found

Tags: office365, office365-restapi

**Note:** Same flow is working for Office 365 license.

Exchange Setup information:
We have a hybrid environment, with primary exchange server being on-premise and are archiving user mails boxes in exchange online.

Licensing:
Exchange Online Archiving

Scenario:
We are using [Office 365 rest apis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/api-catalog).
I have used Global admin authorization and stored the resulting refresh token in secure location. Using refresh token, I fetch access token. This access token is then used to fetch User's Mail endpoint.

Then to fetch users mail folder, I create new access_token of [client_credentials type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/azure/dn645543.aspx) and then query for folder listing on the above endpoint.

Below is the detailed request/response.
user_name and access_token has been intentionally removed for privacy reasons.

```
** REQUEST START (Sat Apr 23 07:40:28 2016) **
REQUEST: GET https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/users('<user_name>')/folders/?$top=100
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
accept: application/json
User-Agent: python-requests/2.4.1 CPython/2.7.8 Linux/3.13.0-83-generic
Connection: keep-alive
content-type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer <access_token>
None
* * * *
RESPONSE (404)
x-calculatedbetarget: AM2PR05MB1089.eurprd05.prod.outlook.com
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
transfer-encoding: chunked
request-id: 8c9ac8a6-8fe7-46f6-8dcc-1fff8b1ac8ac
x-aspnet-version: 4.0.30319
server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
cache-control: private
x-beserver: AM2PR05MB1089
x-diaginfo: AM2PR05MB1089
x-feserver: BN1PR08CA0019
set-cookie: exchangecookie=309073c961cb44798302c8eb2fee0188; expires=Sun, 23-Apr-2017 07:40:28 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
date: Sat, 23 Apr 2016 07:40:28 GMT
odata-version: 4.0
content-type: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8
x-backendhttpstatus: 404
{"error":{"code":"ErrorFolderNotFound","message":"The specified folder could not be found in the store."}}
```

My question:

1. Are office 365 rest APIs not supported for exchange online archiving license? If they are supported, then why I am getting 404 error with message "specified folder not found"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I tested, if the user does not have a primary mailbox on Exchange Online, you will get the 404 error. For example, a user does not exists in Azure AD or a user exists in Azure AD, but does not have a Exchange Online licence ([Compare Exchange Online plans](https://products.office.com/en/exchange/compare-microsoft-exchange-online-plans))

In your case, the user licence is "Exchange Online Archiving", which is a cloud-based, enterprise-class archiving solution that helps you to solve archiving, compliance, regulatory, and eDiscovery challenges. But it does not provide user a primary mailbox on Exchange Online, that's why the user will get 404 error when trying to find the primary mailbox.

**Update#1:**

I assume the hybrid environment is as following: Exchange on-premise + Exchange Online (Exchange Online Plan 1 or 2 + Exchange Online Archiving) .

Some users mailbox are fully on Exchange online, but others's mailbox are on the on-premise Exchange Server (please correct me if I have any misunderstanding).

Currently, the Office 365 API does not support accessing the achieve mailboxes.

For the users whose primary mailboxes are on the on-premise Exchange Server. Since the Office 365 API applies to the Exchange Online but not applies to Exchange on-premise, you are not able to use the Office 365 API on these users.
[image]

For the users whose primary mailbox are on the Exchange online (Exchange Online Plan 1 or 2 users), you will be able to user the Office 365 API to access the mailbox.

To access mailbox in on-premise Exchange Server, you can consider using the [EWS API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb204119(v=exchg.150).aspx).

Comment: I am providing correct username only. In the above request,  I have intentionally removed actual user email id for privacy reasons. Same case is with access_token.

Comment: @Naveen, after comparing the "Exchange Online Archiving" and "Exchange Online Plan", I've updated my answer.

Comment: Jeffrey Chen - MSFT: Primary mailbox existence error message is different. If user's primary mailbox doesn't exist, same API returns _"(404, u'{"error":{"code":"ErrorNonExistentMailbox","message":"The SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it."}}')"_. Mailbox error was observed for different tenant. While the one I reported above says "The specified folder could not be found in the store.". So these 2 are different scenarios.

Comment: @Naveen, thanks for pointing out this. Currently, I do not have a "Exchange Online Archiving" account to make a test. But have you tried to use the https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/users('<user_name>')/folders?$top=100 (remove the '/' before '?').

Comment: Chen  I don't have access to change calls, so won't be able to test it. Although same call works for other Office 365 licenses.

Comment: I did try same API and removing the '/' before '?', still no success. Same result.

Comment: @Naveen, thanks for trying this, I've updated my answer, see update#1.